# Android listview in listview append data

Tags: java, android

*I want do design activity like that*:
[image]

i do first part: so i do activity with listview on it, create one more activity(and put there fields like image title name... to do it in adapter scheme-like), and write in activity class such code (with adapter):

```
***
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.bank_exchanger_list_element,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_location_name, TAG_address, TAG_exchanger_type_name, TAG_latitude, TAG_longitude }, new int[] {
                        R.id.bank_e_n, R.id.nas_punkt_e_n , R.id.adress_obm_e_n , R.id.tip_obm_e_n , R.id.shirota_e_n , R.id.dolgota_e_n });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
***
```

my problem is how to do deeper listview: so put one more listview in listview (for listview1 title1 you can see something one, two: this is new listview in my listview)... But how can i do this? Please give examples with code...

Just put on one listview another listview and put it all in code to work...

(also i parse json data, where i have childrens, and must append them to parent), here is json:

```
{
   "bank_exchangers":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"*** №600",
         "address":"******* ",
         "location_id":3,
         "latitude":null,
         "longitude":null,
         "exchanger_type_id":1,
         "location_name":"Minsk",
         "exchanger_type_name":"normal",
         "currency_values":[
            {
               "id":2,
               "currency_list_id":1,
               "value":8620.0,
               "direction_of_exchange_id":1,
               "exchanger_list_id":1
            },
            {
               "id":1,
               "currency_list_id":1,
               "value":8700.0,
               "direction_of_exchange_id":2,
               "exchanger_list_id":1
            },
            {
               "id":4,
               "currency_list_id":2,
               "value":11500.0,
               "direction_of_exchange_id":1,
               "exchanger_list_id":1
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "currency_list_id":2,
               "value":11100.0,
               "direction_of_exchange_id":2,
               "exchanger_list_id":1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)**.

Initially populate the **parent ListView** and then when `currency_values list item` is clicked, you  can expand it to populate the **child ListView**.

Comment: could i custom ExpandableListView so that title etc look's like i do with listview?

Comment: but i must to use two lists.... what about: Initially populate the parent ListView and then when currency_values list item is clicked, you can expand it to populate the child ListView.      What do you mean?

Comment: 1. Yes, it is customizable.

Comment: 2. Have a look at http://www.coderzheaven.com/expandable-listview-android-simpleexpandablelistadapter-simple-example/ and http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html and you would understand what I am talking about.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265328/expandablelist-add-children-data-java-add-map-to-array-of-maps